# How to make a string an already-existing variable?

Tags: python

I can't seem to turn a string into a corresponding variable.

point1 is a defined tuple (100, 100), but once I combined "point" and 1, it stays a string and doesn't return (100, 100).

I'd like to know if there's a way to make the string that existing variable, or if there's a way to combine "point" and "1" without turning either of them into strings. (I combined "point" and "1" using format.)

```
point1 = (100, 100)

def point(step):
    return "point{}".format(step)

print(point1)
print(point(1))
print(tuple(point(1)))
```

I want "point(1)" to return "(100,100)" but it returns "point1".

.

Edit(??): **Thank you so much everyone! All of these answers helped so much! ^^**

My question is unique from the variables variables question, because this one is solved simply by putting the string inside eval() or globals().

eg:

```
point1 = (100,100)

print(point1)
print("point1")
print(eval("point1"))

# or

def point(step):
    return globals()[f"point{step}"]

print(point(1))
```

This gives me

(100, 100)

point1

(100, 100)

(100, 100)

Comment: You can evaluate strings as python expressions but there is almost always a better way

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm very new to python and coding in general. I'll look this up, and if I still have problems, I guess I'll ask around.

Comment: use list or dictionary to keep many values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `eval` for this, normally considered a litle risky but generally okay provided you can control what it's actually evaluating:

```
def point(step):
    try:
        return eval("point{}".format(step))
    except:
        return None

point1 = (100, 100)
print(point1)
print(point(1))
print(point(2))
```

This outputs:

```
(100, 100)
(100, 100)
None
```

If you would rather receive an exception than default to `None`, simply remove the `try/except` stuff:

```
def point(step):
    return eval("point{}".format(step))
```

---

Of course, if the intent here is to have a number of points (where you may not know the quantity in advance), Python has lists to do exactly that:

```
point = [(100, 100), (7, 42)]
```

Then you can reference `point[0]` and `point[1]` to get the individual tuples.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you’re trying to access the global variable using a string. Using `globals()` will safely do this. Using `eval` can be very bad especially when passing user input to it.

```
def point(step):
    return globals()[f"point{step}"]
```

Although this seems you’re trying to access a variable amount of points. If so why not use a list:

```
points = [(100,100), ...]
```

Then to access the first point just use

```
points[0]
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that lists can contain tuples too. Thanks so much, I'll probably use this a lot for my code! :D

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to get the value by string:

```
def point(step):
    v = globals()[f"point{step}"]
    return f"{v}"
```

Then

```
print(point(1))
```

will print

```
(100, 100)
```

Comment: Whoa that's a cool way to do it! I might use this way because eval() is apparently evil(??). I don't know why though. Thanks so much for the help!